# How to request and use a struct (without a struct instance!) inside a generic function?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have this code:

```rust
fn func<T, U>(f: T) where T: Fn()-> U, U: MyTrait {
    let state = f();
    // ...
}
```

`f` here is just a `new` function from a trait `MyTrait` for some struct. I want to have a function which works with every struct implementing `MyTrait`, and there is `new` method for that trait I want to call for `state`.

How can I pass the struct (not a value with type of that struct) into a function with restriction on the specific trait been implemented for that struct?

Comment: You mean your trait has a function `new()` that you want to call in your `fun()`?

Comment: Your question is really confusing to me at least. As far as I understand, you can achieve this as `fn func<T: MyTrait>(arg: T){let state = T::new();}`

Comment: Yes, and there is high chance as soon as it stops to be confusing, I find the answer. :-. Anyway, I want to pass the type of the structure into the function. `arg: T` is a function here, and I want to pass the type to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to *pass* any parameter; the *type parameter* `U` you already have is all you need.

```rust
fn func<U>(...)
where 
   U: MyTrait
{
    ...
    let state = U::new();
    ...
}
```

Or did you mean you want a generic implementation of just `Fn() -> U`? That's even easier: `U::new` is already that. Example using `Default` as the trait, but you can use any trait in the same way:

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn print_instance<T: Debug, F: Fn() -> T>(f: F) {
    println!("{:?}", f());
}

fn print_default<T: Debug + Default>() {
    print_instance::<T, _>(Default::default);
}

fn main() {
    print_default::<Vec<i32>>();
    print_default::<f32>();
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes, you are totally right! I was under impression I MUST to write something inside `(...)`, but yes, it's here.